# extjs grid referesh icons not displaying

Tags: extjs, grid, icons, html-editor

I'm using using Extjs 4.0.7 version. 
Html editor icon images, grid refresh and paging button images are not displaying.

I checked another working setup, there i found x-tbar-loading class for grid refresh icon
but  in the setup i'm using on my system, the above calss is not found. But the css and js files are same as the working setup.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you every find an answer for this?  I am having the same issue on 4.2.1.

Comment: Make sure that all the resource files has been included properly. Or Update your ext-all.js file..

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you included the resources shipped with the distribution.
Also there is really no need to hang back to 4.0.7  - lots of issues have been fixed in 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue using Ext JS 4.2.1. My application skeleton was created using Sencha CMD.  In order to get things working again, I need to rebuild the application using the following commands.  It seemed to need both:

```
sencha app build
sencha app refresh
```

Not sure of the exact order, but after doing that, I was able to get things working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need add

Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();